# How much influence do president-elects have before inauguration?

Tags: united-states, president

In the US, assuming that a president-elect isn't a Vice President already, how much influence do they have before they get sworn in/inaugurated?

Comment: @CandiedOrange I'm trying to exclude scenarios like Bush senior going from VP to P and instead focus on scenarios like Hillary Clinton or Trump becoming president.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

President-elects have very little influence on before they are sworn in. They can be influential in setting what future goals and directions their party will take in the coming years, but the day to day activities during the lame duck session aren't something they have much control over.

President-elects don't have a lot of time to try to influence anything the current government is doing, because the months spent between election and inauguration are spent planning the hundreds of appointments and staff hires needed to make a smooth transition.