# What powers does a US president have between the end of an election and the inauguration of the next president?

Tags: united-states, president, political-transitions

I read [a tweet](https://twitter.com/iyad_elbaghdadi/status/1268943280840085507) earlier asking the hypothetical question of "what could Trump do between November and January if he lost the election?"

In the UK, the election is lost and the winners enter 10 Downing Street. What power does the US President have after he has lost the election?

Comment: I didn't cast a close vote (yet), but I might, because this questions seems to be asking for pure speculation. *Legally* and *institutionally* a president's power does not change when he loses the election. But that doesn't seem to be what you're asking; you seem to be asking what Trump *personally* might do with that power, given his temperamental, capricious, and narcissistic nature. That's far too speculative to be worthwhile.

Comment: I'm not asking what he might or might not do, I'm simply curious if during that 3 months he has all the same power/responsibility as he did before losing the election.

Comment: Related (but not duplicate): [How much influence do president-elects have before inauguration?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/11972/19301), [In the US, why is there such a long time between the elections and inauguration](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/826/19301)

Comment: That's simplifying the UK position a little. It's perfectly possible (and has happened) for a party to lose but for the incumbent prime minister to remain in office while the other party(s) sort themselves out e.g. in a hung parliament.

Comment: Summary of the excellent answers below: CDJB: His legal powers do not change. Machavity: His influence is less, because his successor can undo much of what he's done, and his opponents can just wait for the new president. Bobson: He can do some things that *cannot* be undone and for which he needs no support, like granting controversial pardons.

Comment: @JBentley That very seldom happens, and when it does the incumbent in Downing Street, under the British system is in a very weak position as concerns any radical or capricious action. Controls can be exercised by any of a) parliament, b) the Cabinet Secretary, and c) the sovereign. It is difficult to see how such a person could do anything precipitate - it is entirely a caretaker role.

Comment: @ws2 Yes, I don't dispute any of that. I was merely correcting the OP's assumption that "In the UK, the election is lost and the winners enter 10 Downing Street"

Comment: @JBentley Normally that is what happens. The new PM moves in the morning after.  The 2010 situation was highly unusual. But had Gordon Brown, while sitting there, acted totally out of character and attempted to launch a nuclear strike, Cameron and Clegg would have been on the phone to Buck House and in the unlikely event GB 
 had refused a summons - a detachment of the Household Cavalry would have been sent to get him, I feel sure. Any order to the armed services could be overridden by an Order in Council - Queen and a quorum of Privy Councillors.

Comment: @ws2 Yes, and all of that would be a suitable answer if the question had been based on the UK instead of the US. "Normally happens" doesn't mean "always happens", and so it is perfectly valid to consider what the rules are when the exceptions occur.

Comment: @TedWrigley: Your interpretation is correct for the question asked in that tweet, but OP's title is a different question, focusing on what _any US president_ could do. OP's question doesn't specifically point at Trump.

Comment: @Flater: Arguably true, but the difference between the title and the body called for clarification.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The 20th Amendment to the US Constitution states:

> The terms of the President and the Vice President **shall end at noon on
> the 20th day of January**, and the terms of Senators and Representatives
> at noon on the 3d day of January, of the years in which such terms
> would have ended if this article had not been ratified; and the terms
> of their successors shall then begin.

The incumbent President, therefore, legally retains all powers he had during most of his term in the 72-78 day period between Election Day (2nd-8th November) and the inauguration of the new President. According to the Congressional Research Service's publication, [*Presidential Transitions: Issues Involving Outgoing and Incoming Administrations*](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/misc/RL34722.pdf):

> The President’s authority to exercise power begins immediately upon
> being sworn into office and continues until he is no longer the
> officeholder. By the same token, while congressional oversight of the
> executive branch is continuous, some activities may take on special
> significance at the end or beginning of an Administration. The
> disposition of government records (including presidential records and
> vice presidential records), protections against “burrowing in” (which
> involves the conversion of political appointees to career status in
> the civil service), the granting of pardons, and the issuance of
> “midnight rules” are four activities associated largely with the
> outgoing President’s Administration. The incumbent President may also
> submit a budget to Congress, or he may defer to his successor on this
> matter.

Comment: Would an impeachment help keep the outgoing president in check should he start to behave (more) erratically?

Comment: Impeachment has no effect until the Senate confirms it, which is called "removal".  Removal has immediate and total effect and all powers devolve to the Vice President

Comment: What is specifically meant by "the disposition of government records"?  Is it implying that past administrations have destroyed or hidden records?

Comment: @DrSheldon yes - see the [Presidential Records Act](https://www.archives.gov/presidential-libraries/laws/1978-act.html). "Allows the incumbent President to dispose of records that no longer have administrative, historical, informational, or evidentiary value, once the views of the Archivist of the United States on the proposed disposal have been obtained in writing."

Answer (score 26):

The other two answers are correct that [legally, nothing changes](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/54061/2130) but [practically, there's not much you can do](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/54059/2130).  However, there's one *effective* "power" that a lame duck president has which they do not normally have:  The ability to pardon without political consequences.

A president can pardon for any federal crime at any time, and no one (even their successor) can undo that.  However, if they pardon someone highly controversial, it may have an effect on their chances of being reelected or their party's performance in the next Congressional election.  But if they're not going to run again in the future, and there will be almost two years of other news events before the next Congressional election, they can pardon whomever they want without suffering for it, and their successor can't undo that.

For example, a third of the [people Obama pardoned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_granted_executive_clemency_by_Barack_Obama) during his eight years in office were in those months after the 2016 elections, half them on his very last day.

Comment: Seems kinda weird to single out Obama (and only Obama) here, since *every* president in my lifetime has done the same (and I'm past half a century now). However, I'll allow that he *was* the last POTUS to be in this situation.

Comment: Just went and checked, and Bush II only pardoned 2 of his 18 (11%) after his party lost the 2008 election. However *his* last election was in 2004, and he issued 73% of his pardons after that day.

Comment: It's important to note that no one can overturn a presidential pardon, not even the new president. So unlike his Executive Orders, when he does this, it *stays* done.

Comment: @T.E.D. The most recent and the one who used it the most.  But it’s definitely a common practice.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson Good call. I’d said that in a comment on another answer, but forgot to explicitly say it in mind, too. Added.

Answer (score 20):

The "lame duck" period (the three months between election and inauguration) doesn't see any differences in Presidential powers. The catch is you're unlikely to do anything in office that your successor cannot undo later. Congress is in the same boat but, historically, an incoming President will have their party in enough control of Congress to prevent any major legislation from being passed. Executive orders can typically be undone by the same powers that created them.

Comment: Pardons and anything that would take effect before January would be the two things that couldn't be undone (although the latter could be halted/reversed, the past can't be rewritten)

Comment: There is plenty a president can do that cant be undone by the next president. This includes: Signing bills into law, appointing judges, and issuing pardons. So I contest the claim that "you are unlikely to do anything in office that your successor cannot undo later" especially given that issuing a bunch of pardons is one of the last things most presidents do before they leave office. I think most presidents are quite likely to do something that cant be undone.

Comment: @Matt I did note that laws the incoming President opposes are unlikely to be passed in my answer

Comment: Is that true though? A current congress has no particular allegiance to a future president.

Comment: @Matt Again, as I noted in my question, typically the outgoing President does not have full control of Congress. Even if they were in the minority, the incoming President's party would filibuster any laws they disagreed with.

Comment: The president never has any amount of control of congress.

Comment: @Matt I don't think he meant legal control, just effective control when the majority party is the same as the President's.

Comment: Assassinations are also unundoable.

Comment: @Matt re: Judicial appointments - provided the senate does not refuse to even consider any lame duck judicial nominees for political reasons.  Not like *that* would ever happen...